# Number theory question with automorphic numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The number 9376 has the property that the last four digits of 9376^2 are 9376, also know as 9376 being an automorphic number. How many four-digit numbers have this property? Are there values of n greater than 4 such that there is at least one n-digit number x that has this property? I know that there are no other automorphic numbers with 4 digits and there are automorphic numbers with more than 4 digits, but I need to prove this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just directly prove this. Suppose $n$ is $4$-digit automorphic. Then $n^2 - n \equiv 0 \bmod 10000$. Let's decompose this into the two prime power equations:

$$n^2 - n \equiv 0 \bmod 16$$

$$n^2 - n \equiv 0 \bmod 625$$

As $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$, and as $n$ is relatively prime to $n-1$, we must have that $n \equiv 0 \bmod 2^4$ and $n \equiv 1 \bmod 5^4$, or $n \equiv 1 \bmod 2^4$ and $n \equiv 0 \bmod 5^4$ (if $n$ is equivalent to $0$ mod both, then $n$ is $0$).

I will work with the first set of conditions. So $n \equiv 1 \bmod 625$ means that $n = 1 + 625k$ for some $k$. But then $n = 1 + 625k \equiv 1 + k \bmod 16$, so that $k \equiv 15 \bmod 16$.

Putting these together, $n = 1 + 625(15 + 16l) = 9376 + 10000l$ for some $l$. So if $n$ is 4 digits and satisfies this set of conditions, then $n = 9376$. I'll leave the other case to you.

For more digits, you might just check that $109376$ is also automorphic. This is quickly proved with the same technique above. You might notice that we didn't actually assume the number of digits of $n$ anywhere - so there are only two sets of final digits an automorphic number might have. One happens to end in $9376$ as shown here.

Comment: Why does n^2 - n equal 0mod(16) or 625? Doesn't 0 mod(n) always equal 0?

Comment: Where do you see $0 = 0$ somewhere? I'm referring to the Chinese remainder theorem to decompose.

Comment: Sorry, not the most knowledgable about number theory. I was talking about the line n^2 − n ≡ 0mod16 because I was under the belief that 0 mod(x) is always equal to 0, so we would get n^2 - n ≡ 0.

Comment: How about this. Anytime I wrote $a \equiv b \bmod x$, you should read it as "$x$ divides $a - b$." Since $10000$ divides $n^2 - n$, then we have both $16$ and $25$ divides $n^2 - n$. As $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$, we must have that $16$ divides one of $n$ and $n-1$,... and so on. This will make the answer understandable without seeing the potentially confusing word "mod"

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, sorry to reopen this but I had a few more questions. First, You say that you will leave the other case to me, but how would you actually disprove that there is a 4-digit n that satisfies the conditions? Also, is there a method besides previous knowledge that would allow me to prove the existence of a n with more than four digits?

Comment: Did you try the other case? If you did, write it down and I can talk to you about it. Secondly, we didn't use any previous knowledge. This is entirely self contained and from first principles.

Comment: I looked at the other cases for a little while and I got them, but for outside knowledge I was talking about the portion where you said you might just check that 109376 is automorphic. How would you get this arbitrary number to actually check with in the first place?

Comment: The exact same process I wrote above works for $k$ digits instead of $4$. Just do the same process. Alternatively, you can actually write a pair of recurrence relations that generate them all.

Comment: Awesome. One final thing, in $n=1+625k≡1+k mod16$, is it $1 + (k mod16)$ or $(1 + k) mod16$?

Comment: Ah, that's a good question. You're right that this isn't clear from my explanation of mods above. I mean $(1 + k) \mod 16$.

Comment: One more thing, I understand what the sequance $n=1+625k≡1+k$ mod 16 and $ k≡15$ mod 16 means, but I don't understant the steps taken from $1+625k≡1+k$ mod 16, so that $k≡15$ mod16.

Comment: We know that $n = 1+625k \equiv 0 \mod 16$, which reduces to $1 + k \equiv 0 \mod 16$. But this means that $1 \equiv -k$, or rather that $k \equiv -1 \equiv 15 \mod 16$.

Comment: How exactly do you reduce $1 + 625k ≡ 0 $mod 16 to $1 + k ≡ 0$ mod 16?

Comment: By noticing that $624 = 39*16$. So if $16$ divides $1 + 625k$, then it divides $1+k+(16\cdot 624k)$, which means it divides $1+k$. People refer to this as "reducing mod 16".

Comment: @mixedmath♦: "As n2−n=n(n−1), and as n is relatively prime to n−1, we must have that n≡0mod24 and n≡1mod54, or n≡1mod24 and n≡0mod54 (if n is equivalent to 0 mod both, then n is 0)."
Where does this come from?