# Peculiar numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is from the weekly math challenge of the French newspaper *Le Monde*.

> "Magical" numbers have a remarkable property: when one of them, say $n$, is squared, it is such that $n^2$ ends with $n$.
>
> For example, $76$ is one of those since $76^2=5776$
>
> Can you list these numbers without a CAS or a calculator ?

$u$ is such number if and only if $\displaystyle u(u-1)=10^qm$ where $q$ is the number of digits of $u$ (namely $\displaystyle \left\lfloor\frac{\ln(u)}{\ln(10)}\right\rfloor+1)$ and $m$ is arbitrary.

Using the fact that $u$ and $u-1$ are coprime , I'm able to find the first few numbers by some narrowed trial-and-error : $5,6,25,76,376,625$.

But it becomes tedious with $4$ digit numbers...

Can someone answer the original question ?

Comment: You must have $u(u-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^q}$ for $p = 2$ and $p = 5$. Chinese remainder it.

Comment: don't forget 0 and 1. Further http://oeis.org/A003226

Comment: In fact, you can also write a recurrence relation that gives you the "magical" numbers of a longer length. I [wrote an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/692185/9754) about this type of number before. They're called "automorphic numbers."

Comment: I didn't want to add an answer since I don't have a full explanation, but so far the following numbers have this property:

Comment: 1,5,6,25,76,376,625,9376,90625,109376,890625,2890625,7109376,12890625,87109376

Answer (score 2):

If you just look at the units digit, you see that magical numbers must end in $0, 1, 5, $ or $6$. We will show that the only magical numbers that end in $1$ are $1, 01, 001, \dots$.

If $u$ is a two-digit number that ends in 1, then $u = 10x + 1$ for some digit $x$.

\begin{align}
         u(u - 1) &\equiv 0 \pmod{100}\\
   (10n + 1)(10n) &\equiv 0 \pmod{100}\\
              10n &\equiv 0 \pmod{100}\\
                n &\equiv 0 \pmod{10}\\
\end{align}

So $u = 01$. Suppose, inductively, that the only $q$-digit magical number that ends in $1$ is $000\dots01$, where there are $q - 1$ $0$s to the left of $1$.
Then a $(q+1)$-digit magical number that ends in $1$ must look like $u = 10^q x + 1$ for some digit $x$. Reasoning similar to that shown above will show that $x = 0$. It follows by induction that then only magical numbers that end in $1$ are  $1, 01, 001, \dots$.

Similar reasoning will show that the only magical nubers that end in $0$ are $0, 00, 000, \dots$

There is a peculiar pattern with the magic numbers that end in $5$. The first three are listed below.

```
5²   =     25
25²  =    625
625² = 390625
```

Note the magical numbers are formed by prepending a digit to the previous magic number.

Note also that the digit prepended is the first nonrepeated digit in $n^2$.

So the next three numbers must be

```
0625²   =       390625
90625²  =   8212890625
890625² = 793212890625
```

Where we have to accept $0625$ as a four-digit number.

We can prove this.

Let $N$ be a q-digit magical number that ends in $5$.

We seek a digit $\alpha$ such that the $(q+1)$-digit number 
$N' = 10^q\alpha + N$ is the next magical number that ends in 5.

\begin{align}
   N'^2 - N' &\equiv 0 \pod{10^{q+1}}\\
   (10^q\alpha + N)^2 - (10^q\alpha + N) &\equiv 0 \pod{10^{q+1}}\\
   2 \cdot 10^q\alpha N - 10^q\alpha  + N^2 - N &\equiv 0 \pod{10^{q+1}}\\
   -10^q\alpha  + N^2 - N &\equiv 0 \pod{10^{q+1}}\\
   10^q\alpha  &\equiv N^2 - N \pod{10^{q+1}}\\
   \alpha  &\equiv \dfrac{N^2 - N}{10^q} \pod{10}\\
\end{align}

Which means that $\alpha$ is the first nonrepeating digit of $N^2$.

To find the magical numbers that end in $6$, note that

```
6²   =     36  and  5 + 6 = 11
76²  =   5776  and  25 + 76 = 101
376² = 141376  and  625 + 376 = 1001
```

It seems that the two $q$-digit magical numbers, the one that ends in $5$ and the other that ends in $6$,  sum to $10^q + 1$.

It turns out that this is easy to prove.

Let $N$ be a q-digit magical number that ends in $5$. Then

\begin{align}
   (10^q + 1 - N)^2 - (10^q + 1 - N)
      &\equiv  (1 - N)^2 - (1 - N) \pod{10^q}\\
      &\equiv  N^2 - N \pod{10^q}\\
      &\equiv  0 \pod{10^q}\\
\end{align}

so we find

```
10001   -   0625 =   9376  and  9376²   =    87909376
100001  -  90625 =  09376  and  09376²  =    87909376
1000001 - 890625 = 109376  and  109376² = 11963109376
```