# Pattern on last digits of numbers to a certain power

Tags: number-theory

There are 4 one-digit numbers which when squared have a last digit equal to the first number. They are 0,1,5 and 6.

There are 2 two-digit numbers which when squared have their last two digits equal to the first number. They are 25 and 76.

There are 2 three-digit numbers which when squared have their last three digits equal to the first number. They are 625 and 376. (i.e. 376^2 = 141376, ends with 376, 625^2 = 390625, ends with 625)

This pattern can be continued for n-digit numbers which when squared have their last n-digits equal to the former number.

This pattern can continue indefinitely. [The proof is left to the reader]

i.e. Prove $5, 25, 625, 0625, 90625, 890625,...$ (we will count 0625 as part of the pattern even though it is not a four digit number as only 0 works and also because it continues the pattern.) and $6, 76, 376, 9376, 09376, 109376, 7109376, 87103976,...$ will continue indefinitely.

However, that cannot just be my question since it's been asked before. (automorphic numbers)

Therefore, what about other powers? ($n^3, n^4$)

[**Edit**: I forgot to mention and so on. So I actually wanted a general case $n^i$]

Or even to the power of itself? ($n^n$)

Comment: For cube: [...212890624](https://oeis.org/A091664), [...7109375](https://oeis.org/A091663)

Comment: For fourth power: $x^4-x=(x^2-x)(x^2+x+1)$, so the two numbers in the question already satisfy it.

Comment: I used program to validate that the fourth power only has four solutions: the two in the question, 1, 0.

Comment: As for to itself: I've used program to found these solutions: $1,1001,2001,2751,3001,4001,5001,5376,6001,6751,7001,8001,9001,10001,10751,11001,12001,13001,13376,14001,14751,15001,15625,16001,17001,18001,18751,19001,20001,21001,21376,22001,22751,23001,24001,25001,26001,26751,27001,28001,29001,29376,30001,30751,31001,31249,32001,33001,34001,34751,35001,36001,37001,37376,38001,38751,39001,40001,41001,42001,42751,43001,44001,45001,45376,46001,46751,47001,48001,49001,50001,50751,51001,52001,53001,53376,54001,54751,55001,56001,57001,58001,58751,59001,60001,61001,\cdots$

Comment: Clearly most of them cannot be built on indefinitely, but you do observe a rather unsurprising pattern: they end (again!) in $1$ or $751$ or $376$ or $625$.

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers are called Automorphic numbers (as you just said). There is a longer list here:

https://oeis.org/A007185 is $5^{2^n}$ $\mod 10^n$

https://oeis.org/A016090 is $16^{5^n}$ $\mod 10^n$

There are also other sequences like these for any $a$, coprime to $10$, the Automarphic sequence is $a^{10^n}$ $=$ 1 $\mod 10^n$, and if $a$ $=$ $10x$, then $a^n$ $=$ 0 $\mod 10^n$.

$n^3$, any string of digits ending in 1, 3, 7, 9 can be the ending digits of a perfect cube, for other strings, the last three digits are a multiple of 8, 125 or just 000 (for numbers $n$ divisible by 10)

If $x$ is coprime to 10, then there is an integer $a$ such that:

$a^a$ $=$ $x$ $\mod 10^n$, so it is easy to see that the last digit of $a^a$ is either 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd do this for $n^n$, but other powers can be done using modular arithmetic.  For example, if you want to know what numbers, when cubed, have the last $2$ digits of the original number, you are solving

$$n^3\equiv n\pmod{100}$$

$$n^3-n=n(n+1)(n-1)\equiv0\pmod{100}$$

In other words, $n(n-1)(n+1)$ is a multiple of $100$.  First, take a look at when it's a multiple of $4$.  Solutions for this are $n\equiv0,1$ or $3\pmod4$.  Now to see when it's a multiple of $25$.  If any of the $3$ factors are multiples of $5$, the remaining $2$ factors cannot. So we have $n\equiv-1,0,$ or $1\pmod{25}$.  So if $n$ ends in $00,01,24,25,49,51,75,76,$ or $99$, $n^3$ should as well.

Higher powers get more complicated.  As for the fourth power, the equation becomes

$$(n^2-n)(n^2+n+1)\equiv0\pmod{10^a}$$

That second term does not seem to be a multiple of $2$ or $5$ for any value of $n$.  Therefore, the only numbers where $n$ and $n^4$ share trailing digits are those where $n$ and $n^2$ share trailing digits.

Comment: See this link : [Peculiar Numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855690/peculiar-numbers/1284375#1284375)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, inductively, that we have a q-digit number, $N$, for which 
$N^n \equiv N \pmod{10^q}$ and we seek to prepend a digit, $k$ to N, resulting in a (q+1)-digit number $\widehat N = 10^qk+N$, 
such that $\widehat N^n \equiv \widehat N \pmod{10^{q+1}}$

\begin{align}
   \widehat N^n &\equiv \widehat N \pmod{10^{q+1}}\\
   (10^qk + N)^n &\equiv 10^qk + N \pmod{10^{q+1}}\\
   n(10^qk)(N^{n-1}) + N^n &\equiv 10^qk + N \pmod{10^{q+1}}\\
   (1-nN^{n-1})10^qk &\equiv N^n - N \pmod{10^{q+1}}\\
   (1-nN^{n-1})k &\equiv \dfrac{N^n - N}{10^q} \pmod{10}\tag 1\\
\end{align}

Let's define $d_q = \dfrac{N^n - N}{10^q} \pmod{10}$. Then equation $(1)$ becomes 
$$(1-nN^{n-1})k \equiv d_q \pmod{10}\tag 2$$

Notice that $d_q$ is the first nonrepeating digit of $N^n$ (the $(k+1)^{th}$ digit from the right).

Notice also that $(1-nN^{n-1}) \equiv (1-nk_0^{n-1}) \pmod{10}$ where $k_0$ is the units digit of $N$.

We find 
\begin{align}
     1^2 &\equiv 1 \pmod{10} \\
     2^5 &\equiv 2 \pmod{10} \\
     3^5 &\equiv 3 \pmod{10} \\
     4^3 &\equiv 4 \pmod{10} \\
     5^2 &\equiv 5 \pmod{10} \\
     6^2 &\equiv 6 \pmod{10} \\
     7^5 &\equiv 7 \pmod{10} \\
     8^5 &\equiv 8 \pmod{10} \\
     9^3 &\equiv 9 \pmod{10} \\
\end{align}

So, if you **require** that $x^n \equiv x \pmod{10}$, we need only consider $n = 2,3,$ and $5$.

---

The case $n = 2$ has been handled in this Stack Exchange article on [pecular numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855690/peculiar-numbers/1284375#1284375).

---

For the case $n = 3, k_0=4$ we find that 
$(1-nk_0^{n-1}) \equiv (1-(3)(4^2)) \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$. So the solution to equation $(1)$ is $k \equiv 7\,\dfrac{N^n - N}{10^q} \pmod{10}$, We list the first $5$ numbers in this pattern.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
    \text{q} & \text{N} & N^3 \mod{10^{q+1}} & k \pmod{10} \\
    \hline
    1 &     4 &     64 & 2 \\
    2 &    24 &    824 & 6 \\
    3 &   624 &   0624 & 0 \\
    4 &  0624 &  70624 & 9 \\
    5 & 90624 & 490624 & 8 \\
\end{array}

For the case $n = 3, k_0=9$ we find that 
$(1-nk_0^{n-1}) \equiv 8 \pmod{10}$. So equation $(2)$ becomes 
$8k \equiv d_q \pmod{10}$. We can only solve for $k$ when $d_q$ is an even number, in which case $k \equiv 2d_q \pmod 5$ and there will be two solutions modulo $10$. We list the first few numbers in this pattern.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
    \text{q} & \text{N} & N^3 \mod{10^{q+1}} & k \pmod{10} \\
    \hline
    1 &     9 &     29 & 4,9 \\
    \hline
    2 &    49 &    649 & 2,7 \\
    2 &    99 &    299 & 4,9 \\
    \hline
    3 &   249 &   8249 & 6,1 \\
    3 &   749 &   9749 & \cdots \\
    3 &   499 &   1499 & \cdots \\
    3 &   999 &   2999 & 4,9 \\
    \hline
    4 &  6249 &  56249 & \cdots \\
    4 &  1249 &  41249 & 8,3 \\
    4 &  4999 &  14999 & \cdots \\
    4 &  9999 &  29999 & 4,9 \\
\end{array}

---

For the case $n = 5, k_0=2$ we find that 
$(1-nk_0^{n-1}) \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$. So equation $(2)$ becomes 
$k \equiv d_q \pmod{10}$. We list the first few numbers in this pattern.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
    \text{q} & \text{N} & N^5 \mod{10^{q+1}} & k \pmod{10} \\
    \hline
    1 &     2 &     32 & 3 \\
    2 &    32 &    432 & 4 \\
    3 &   432 &   6432 & 6 \\
    4 &  6432 &  86432 & 8 \\
    5 & 86432 & 186432 & 1 \\
\end{array}

For the case $n = 5, k_0=3$ we find that 
$(1-nk_0^{n-1}) \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$. So equation $(2)$ becomes 
$6k \equiv d_q \pmod{10}$. We can only solve for $k$ when $d_q$ is an even number, in which case $k \equiv d_q \pmod 5$ and there will be two solutions modulo $10$. We list the first few numbers in this pattern.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
    \text{q} & \text{N} & N^5 \mod{10^{q+1}} & k \pmod{10} \\
    \hline
    1 &     3 &     43 & 4,9 \\
    \hline
    2 &    43 &    443 & 4,9 \\
    2 &    93 &    693 & 6,1 \\
    \hline
    3 &   443 &   0443 & 0,5 \\
    3 &   943 &   2943 & 2,7 \\
    3 &   693 &   6693 & 6,1 \\
    3 &   193 &   4193 & 4,9 \\
    \hline
    4 &  0443 &  10443 & \cdots \\
    4 &  5443 &  35443 & \cdots \\
    4 &  2943 &  32943 & \cdots \\
    4 &  7943 &  47943 & 4,9 \\
    4 &  6693 &  16693 & \cdots \\
    4 &  1693 &  91693 & \cdots \\
    4 &  4193 &  04193 & 0,5 \\
    4 &  9193 &  29193 & 2,7 \\
\end{array}

I think you get the idea by now.

There is much that still needs solving. I don't know which of these patterns will continue indefinitely. Nor have I studied what would happen if you started with a two-digit number that repeats, 
$(10k_1 + k_0)^n \equiv 10k_1 + k+0 \pmod{100}$.