# Reverse Automorphic Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computer-science

I recently stumbled across **Automorphic Numbers** ([definition and examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_number)).

> In simple words, a number $n$ is said to be automorphic if last $d(n)$
>   digits of $n^2$ are $n$ itself (where $d(n)$ is the number of digits
>   of n)

Example: $n$ = 890625 is automorphic since $n^2$ = 793212**890625** where last $d(n)$ = 6 digits of $n^2$ are the same as $n$.

I understand that there is recurrence relation to calculate an automorphic number with $2d(n)$ digits given an automorphic number of $d(n)$ digits; given by,

> $n'$ = $(3n^2 - 2n^3)$ $mod$ $10^{2d(n)}$ ([Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692159/number-theory-question-with-automorphic-numbers))

---

Now that I understood this, I started playing with automorphic numbers and tried to find out what I call as **Reverse Automorphic Numbers**. As you might have guessed by now,

> A reverse automorphic number $k$ is a number such that last $d(n)$
>   digits of $k^2$ is the reverse of $k$.

Example: $k = 65766$ is reverse-automorphic since $k^2 = 43251$**66756** where last $d(n) = 6$ digits of $k^2$ are the reverse of $k$.

> I tried finding out the recurrence relation for reverse-automorphic
>   numbers on the same lines as that of automoprhic numbers but could not
>   proceed. How can I find out a recurrence relation for such
>   reverse-automorphic numbers ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: http://oeis.org/A115761 is a superset of the set of "reverse-automorphic" numbers (OEIS does not appear to include the sequence of "reverse automorphic" numbers as a sequence in its own right).

Comment: @Travis Thanks for the link! I am more interested in deriving/proving the non-existence of a generating formula rather than the numbers of the reverse-automorphic sequence.

Comment: Naively one would expect this is pretty difficult, as reversing a substring of a decimal representation is not a particularly natural operation, and at any rate much less so than the corresponding "forward automorphic" operation of reducing modulo $10^n$.

Comment: Yes. Exactly! It does not seem intuitive to me at all. Yet I'm struck trying to solve this. Unable to take this particular thing off my head :(

I also wrote a small program to generate the few reverse-automorphic numbers, hoping to find a pattern. Im publishing them here hoping that the awesome people of Math Community might find some pattern not visible to my relatively untrained eyes.

1, 5, 6, 963, 9867, 65766, 69714, 6317056, 90899553, 169605719, ...